# Route network traffic through multiple switches through subnet

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I previously had an older computer connected to a switch at my work and used the `route` function of the Windows command prompt to send data through my subnet throughout my multiple switches.
I have now replaced the computer with a newer one (the old one died) and need to get this working again.

Everything is connected to the same subnet mask: 255.255.255.128, and I've previously had this working by using just these settings. The only difference is the new computer.

I have attached two pictures of how the network is setup, the only difference being where I connect my computer to the network. If I connect my computer to circuit 1 I'm able to reach all the IPs at 192.168.1.xxx but not 192.168.2.xxx and vice versa.

Network 1:

[image: network circuit with IPs - 1]

Network 2:

[image: network circuit with IPs - 2]

I hope someone's able to help! :) cheers.

Comment: I've had this working previously by connecting my computer to the management switch 1

Comment: You seem ti be conflating 2 layers. You have the ethernet layer, where, assuming the subnet was large.enough everything could talk ti each other (but.that would requirr.255.255.254.0 or courser). You need a router to link the 2 networks, along with default routes or route to the alternative network, but this is absent from your diagram (or its wrong an a switch is actually doing routing or address.translation)